# Can someone help me filter data based on date and time range in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

I want to filter the data with all the records starting 3AM from yesterday until 3 AM today.
What I am doing is limiting the data using the below expression and I am getting the data from yesterday which starts at 3AM but I also get all data from today which I need to limit only till 3AM.

(Date([START_DATETIME_CST])=Date((DateTimeNow()))and
(Hour([START_DATETIME_CST])< 3)
and
(date([START_DATETIME_CST])>= dateadd('dd',-1,Date(DateTimeNow()))and
(Hour([START_DATETIME_CST])>=3)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the logical ANDs, because your date cannot be both yesterday and today; so the middle AND needs to become an OR.
Adjusting some parentheses, this should work for you: requesting that the date is either today with time less than 3 or yesterday with time greater or equal to 3

```
((Date([START_DATETIME_CST])=Date(DateTimeNow())) and (
Hour([START_DATETIME_CST])<3)) OR ((
Date([START_DATETIME_CST])=DateAdd('dd',-1,Date(DateTimeNow()))) and (
Hour([START_DATETIME_CST])>=3))
```